# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am facing issue with exporting `JAR` as runnable from `Eclipse`.

Tried with `maven plugin, spring-boot plugin & simple java project export`.
However, it shows spring.factories file related error. I have already copied and pasted it in the required folder after checking on google.

I need to export a `spring-boot application` which includes some `3rd party JARs` and maven jars(to be downloaded from pom.xml) and properties file.

The Jar should be running from the console or using a batch file in the system.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: are you using springs auto-configuration?

Comment: I have tried both.
1. maven build plugin and tried with clean install, clean re-package:repackage, clean test etc but itsn't working.
2. If I am correct, Yes I am using Springs auto-configuration. EnableAutoConifiguration annotation is used. Also, in pom.xml:
  <start-class>com.tcs.stest.adapter.itsm.initBatch.Application</start-class>

Correct me if my understanding of auto-configuration is wrong as I am new to Springboot.

Comment: Hi All: I think there was some missing plugins related to springboot application. I was creating springboot project and then adding maven dependencies. But after creating maven project, adding springboot dependencies worked. Thank you all for your time. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in `Terminal`

```
mvn install
```

With out test

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

or

```
mvn install -DskipTests=true
```

the jar will be available in `/target` folder

Comment: I am getting below error for above command:

    Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/pc/Desktop/xx/Eclipse-Workspace-Root/JAR_Creation_Example/NewAxway/src/main/java/com/*.java:[3,21] package com.*.*.bs does not exist

Comment: `-Xlint:unchecked ` is deprecated warning. It's not the reason. Some `library` is missing which is required at `line 3`.  Why don't you add all required dependencies in `pom.xml`?